# normalizing mesh in three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl

I'm loading a mesh from an obj file, then trying to normalize it. However, I'm getting strange results. Here is the code for loading and centering the mesh:

```
var manager = new THREE.LoadingManager();
var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader(manager);
loader.load('http://jamesdedge.com/threejs/bunny.obj', function(object) {
  object.traverse(function(child) {
    if(child instanceof THREE.Mesh)
    {
      var geometry = child.geometry;
      var verts = geometry.vertices;
      var ctr = new THREE.Vector3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);


      for(i = 0; i < verts.length; ++i)
        ctr.add(verts[i]);

      ctr.divideScalar(verts.length);

      for(i = 0; i < verts.length; ++i)
        verts[i].sub(ctr);
    }
  });

  scene.add(object);
});
```

This code should just center the mesh on the average of the vertex positions, but it seems to be causing a strange effect. You can see it on my website here: http://jamesdedge.com/threejs/tjs_demo.html

I don't see what is causing this, the ctr variable is giving me a valid vector and subtracting a vector from all the vertices will only reposition it.

Comment: Consider using instead `geometry.mergeVertices(); THREE.GeometryUtils.center( geometry );`

Comment: Bug report filed: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/3897 three.js r.61

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many of the vertices in this model are duplicates (i.e. the same javascript object is contained in the object multiple times), so ctr gets detracted from those vertices multiple times.

One way to address this is issue is to merge the vertices at the start of your traversal function, i.e.

```
var geometry = child.geometry;
geometry.mergeVertices();
```

This will also make your code run a bit faster as it has to process a lot less vertices.

Comment: Yes. 2503 vertices in the data file result in 14K+ vertices in the mesh, and those 14K+ vertices reference the same `Vector3` objects over and over. I consider this a bug in `OBJLoader`. What you have suggested is a good work-around.

Comment: this solved the problem - thanks! wonder why OBJReader does this - I've written the same code before and never created duplicate vertices.

Answer (score 0):

You can use GeometryUtils.center() to center your whole mesh conveniently in the middle of the scene at (0,0,0). Anyway, just look at the source code of that function 
https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/blob/master/src/extras/GeometryUtils.js
This should give you a good idea on how to conquer your problem.